# Cannot get DataContractSerializer to deserialize JSON

Tags: c#, .net, json, asp.net-mvc, serialization

I have a class like

```
[DataContract]
public class BranchFormTemplate
{
    [DataMember]
    public BasicSettingsTemplate BasicSettings { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public LclSeedingSettingsTemplate LclSeedingSettings { get; set; }

    .
    .
    .
```

which I'm trying to instantiate based on a JSON file that is POSTed to the server. What I have is like

```
        HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[0]
        HttpInputStream stream = file.InputStream;
        var dcs = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(BranchFormTemplate));
        BranchFormTemplate branchFormTemplate = dcs.ReadObject(stream) as BranchFormTemplate;
```

and I get the exception

> There was an error deserializing the object of type
>   BranchFormTemplate. The data at the root level is invalid. Line 1,
>   position 1.

What confuses me is that this is a `System.Xml.XmlException` and I'm trying to read JSON, not XML. I basically ripped my code from examples on the internet where the source was JSON format, so I can't figure out what I'm missing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DataContractSerializer` documentation states:

> Serializes and deserializes an instance of a type into an **XML** stream
>   or document using a supplied data contract.

To deserialize json, you need `DataContractJsonSerializer`:

> Serializes objects to the JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) and
>   deserializes JSON data to objects.

Note that if you have a choice - there are better alternatives for parsing JSON. The most widely used one is `JSON.NET` (`Newtonsoft.Json`).